# How do I create a remote repository in my team repository site?

Tags: git

I'm working on a Chef project so I ran `berks cookbook myproject` on my laptop.  I then ran `git init`, `git add -A`, and then `git commit` so that the project is in my local Git repository.  Now I want to push it to the central server that my team uses and add it.

I ran `git remote add baseLauncher git@git.mycompany.com:myteam/baseLauncher.git` which produced no output.  So I thought it worked fine.

Then I ran `git push`, but I got the following error.

> fatal: No configured push destination. Either specify the URL from the
>   command-line or configure a remote repository using
>
> ```
> git remote add <name> <url>
> ```
>
> and then push using the remote name
>
> ```
> git push <name>
> ```

But that's exactly what I did.  I tried searching the git help (useless) and googling for anything on doing this but all of the search returns seemed only to be devoted to 1). How to pull a remote repository 2). How to branch 3). Setting up a central repository that other users will use.

Any ideas on how to do this?

I should note that I'm trying to create the repo on the remote server using the command line.  And that the repo has to go "under" my team's git user name.

Just to be clear, this git server is a host on the network of the company I work for.  I've just been assigned a new project and I wanted to be able to create the repo for this new project on the server remotely.  I assumed that there would be a git command that would enable me to do that.

Comment: "Then I ran "git push" and got the following error:" "...and then push using the remote name: "git push <name>""...  So, you should have run "git push baseLauncher"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This just popped up when I was browsing our Git repository and clicked on one of our repository links.  Apparently it doesn't exist yet because I got this as a response:

> Create a new repository on the command line

```
touch README.md
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin git@git.corp.company.com:MyWorkgroup/project-cd.git
git push -u origin master
```

> Push an existing repository from the command line

```
git remote add origin git@git.corp.company.com:MyWorkgroup/project-cd.git
git push -u origin master
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an article that outlines the entire process as I've learned and implemented it, check it out for full details: **[HOW TO SETUP “PUSH-TO-GIT” DEPLOYMENT WITH SSH](http://divtruth.com/2014/07/how-to-setup-push-to-git-deployment-with-ssh/)**

**SETTING UP THE SERVER**

1. SSH to server
2. Change directory to project root

   `cd public_html/project`
3. Setup repository location and move to that directory

   `mkdir -p project-name.git`

   `cd project-name.git`
4. Setup up a bare git instance

   `git init --bare`
5. Setup a post-receive hook for deployment for when a push is made.

   `touch hooks/post-receive` //create hook

   `chmod a+x hooks/post-receive` //make hook exectuable

*It is one thing to push code to a remote, like github, but in this case when you push commits to this remote you will then want to checkout the files in order for them to actually deploy and we will be doing that in this hook.*

6. In your favorite editor, edit the newly created 'post-receive'
   script (this would either be with an ftp client, using 'view/edit',
   or from SSH terminal you can use VIM editor if you're
   comfortable).Insert this script (modify as necessary for your setup)

```html
#!/bin/bash
# 1. Read STDIN (Format: "from_commit to_commit branch_name")
while read oldrev newrev refname
do
branch=$(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref $refname)
if [ "production" == "$branch" ]; then
`GIT_WORK_TREE=../production git checkout -f production`
echo "Changes deployed to live site'"
fi
if [ "stage" == "$branch" ]; then
`GIT_WORK_TREE=../stage git checkout -f stage`
echo "Changes deployed to stage site'"
fi

if [ "development" == "$branch" ]; then
`GIT_WORK_TREE=../dev git checkout -f development`
echo "Changes deployed to development site'"
fi
done
```

This script is triggered whenever a push is made to this remote server. Many things can happen here, but in this example it simply receives the changes from the branches that are pushed (could be a single branch, could be --all). It then determines which branch was pushed and checkouts the changes to defined directory (GIT_WORK_TREE). The branches and directories must match your structure so **make sure to change as necessary**. Most development teams will at most have a development environment for testing code, a staging environment for stable releases for client review, and obviously a production environment for the live site.

**OR** *if you prefer no branch management* (setting up a git bare repository for each directory [production, staging, development] (this is what I do) and ***instead use this script***

```
#!/bin/bash

# 1. Read STDIN (Format: "from_commit to_commit branch_name")
while read oldrev newrev refname
do
    `GIT_WORK_TREE=../ git checkout -f master`
    echo "Changes deployed to {environment}"
done
```

So you see the beauty of this is when a team of developers commits code they can easily `git push <remote> <branch>` and their changes will automatically be deployed (pushed and checked out) to the respective environment.

Comment: Unfortunately that resulted in:
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
Hi! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
                                                                                        Connection to git.corp.yahoo.com closed.

Comment: It's our company's server that's hosting it.  I'm one member of a team working on a project that I've just been assigned.

Comment: Yes, I've been a systems operator for ten years.  I'm quite familiar with Unix and SSH.

Answer (score 0):

Git is a *distributed version control system* or DVCS, this means that *no one repository has any more significance than any of the others*. For that reason, you cannot create a repo remotely and must be on the machine you're creating the repo at (via SSH, etc).

Creating the repo on a remote location is a relatively straightforward process.

It involves creating the repo with `git init` just like you'd do on your local machine (except you'll be SSHing on the remote machine), and using the `--bare` tag to ensure on git objects are in the repository (and not an actual working directory with actual code, you don't need it since it's not a development machine)

Assuming no special software (like Stash or GitHub), you'll need to SSH into the machine, and create a bare repo with `git init --bare` into a directory you want.

So

```
$> ssh myuser@git.company.com
$> git init --bare myteam/baseLauncher.git
```

Comment: Creating the repo at the remote location was my intent.  I'll update my question so that is more obvious.

Comment: That's what Xtremefaith suggested in his article.  But I don't have permissions to ssh to the remote server.  Since I can execute git commands against the remote server I thought one of those commands would allow me to remotely create a new repository.

Comment: Adding a remote implies that you have either HTTPS access or SSH access to the remote server. If you do not, you cannot run commands and cannot initiate a git repository on the machine. Get someone with SSH access, or look to see if your company is using a software for managing their git repositories (such as Stash or GitHub)